# Proof for basis of subspaces in direct sum being basis of its result

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, direct-sum

Can someone please check, and if necessary, correct my prrof? Thanks

$$
E =  F1 \oplus F2
$$

Since B1 is a basis for F1 and B2 is a basis for F2, prove that B1 U B2 is a basis for E:

Any point of a vectorial space can be described as a linear combinatiom of its basis:
$$
a \in F1\\
a = \alpha B1 : \alpha \in R
$$
Same applies to F2:
$$
b \in F2\\
b = \gamma B2 : \gamma \in R
$$
Therefore, for any point that it's in the sum of F1 and F2, we have:
$$
a+b \in E\\
a+b= \alpha B1 + \gamma B2
$$
By that we can assume that B1 U B2 is a basis for E.

-- UPDATED ANSWER --

I was considering B1 and B2 basis of 1 vector... But it's actually the set of all L.I vectors. Because of that I'll remake my answer:

Any point of a vectorial space can be described as a linear combination of the vectors of its basis:
$$
a \in F1\\
a = \sum_{i=1}^{dim(F1)} \gamma_{i}\cdot V_{i} : V_{i} \in B1, \gamma_{i} \in R \\
$$
Same applies to F2:
$$
b \in F2\\
b = \sum_{i=1}^{dim(F2)} \alpha_{i}\cdot V_{i} : V_{i} \in B2, \alpha_{i} \in R \\
$$
Therefore, for any point that it's in the sum of F1 and F2, we have:
$$
a+b \in E
$$
Since a and b are described by linear combinations of their basis         B1 and B2 respectively, we can assume that $ B1 \cup B2 $ is a basis for E.

Comment: A basis does not necessarily consists in one vector.

Comment: I agree.. but in this example i'm assuming thst B1 and B2 is the set of all basis...

Comment: Maybe, but you multiply it by a single number.

Comment: More like if it's made of 1 vector because of this example...

Comment: I understand that, but writing a proof this way lacks rigour,and it's easy to get a confusing proof.

Comment: You have to write the linear combinations explicitly at some point.

Comment: Hmmm you're right buddy. So it's correct but not so rigorous?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44679/discussion-between-bruno-reis-and-bernard).

Comment: You have an idea of what's happening, and you have to develop it, if possible in a concise way.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is on the way to halfway correct. Your notation $\alpha B1$ is not standard. If it means what I think it means - "a linear combination of elements of $B1$" - then you have proved everything in the sum is a linear combination of elements from the two bases.

It seems from your comment on another answer

> A scalar times a basis of F1

that you are a little confused. A "linear combination of basis vectors" is the same as "in the span of the basis" but is not the same as "a scalar times the basis".

I suggest that you rewrite the proof from scratch without the $\alpha B1$ notation, saying at each step just what you know. For example,

> Since $a \in F1$ I can write it as a linear combination of elements of
>   the basis $B1$ (in just one way).

You have to prove that representation is unique to finish. The parenthetical phrase above will help you.

Comment: Yes this is what i meant in the above comment.. 
I think you mean $a = \alpha b$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \text{span } (B_1)$

Comment: I considered B1 a set of one vector that is a basis for F1... assuming that, is the proof correct?

Comment: @AB1 that' what I meant...

Comment: Can you check if the answer is better @Ethan Bolker ?

Comment: @BrunoReis You have the first half right now. You still need to deal with showing the representation of a vector in the sum is unique.

Comment: @EthanBolker It will be unique because the intersection of the two subspaces is ${0}$ right?

Comment: @BrunoReis That's the idea. You have to use it in your proof to convince your reader.